# Need help In using and executing Face Recognition by OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing, face-recognition

I am currently trying to work on Face Recognition by OpenCV, in Visual Studio.
I am using the code by OpenCV [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html).

I executed the code, and it compiled without any errors.
I am unable to see any output. Do I have to create a CSV file to execute this code? If so, how do I go about it? .
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenCV tutorial page](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) gives all steps for face recognition in details, which contains 3 main steps:

1. Preparing the data.
2. Creating the CSV File.
3. Use the code shown in the page to train and test.

You're probably missing the 1st and 2nd steps.

Comment: I took the AT&T face database, and tried creating the csv file. I had also given the destination folder as the same as the src folder.
the command i used is as follows:
python create_csv.py C:\opencv\sources\modules\contrib\doc\facerec\src.

please guide me as to where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance.